# Javascript passing functions as argument

Tags: javascript

this is probably a very beginner question. Anyways

I want to attach a function the window resize event

Below code works and calls my function

```
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){updateWindowSize();});
```

I somewhere ready that I could also just be passing the name of the function but

```
window.addEventListener('resize',"updateWindowSize");
```

does not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Remove quotes. Just `updateWindowSize` alone.

Comment: pass the function name without quotes.

Comment: In JS functions are first-class citizens. You can use them just like any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just to document this properly.

Answer from Niet the Dark Absol :

You should use `window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowSize);` without que quotation marks around `updateWindowSize`.

Since ES6 you can also use a lambda function in such syntax: `() => updateWindowSize;`, since it has no arguments. But the cleanest way in this case is to use Niets approach, because your lambda is only running another function and neither of them take any arguments.